# List String Session Variables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, session

I'm trying to make a program in ASP.net where a user enters details in a textbox on page 1 (default.aspx), clicks a button and it appears in a listbox in page 2 (about.aspx).

I'm trying to make it so the user can enter as many thing into the textbox on page 1 and they will all appear in the listbox in page 2.

Code on page 1:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    people = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
    people.Add(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Code on page 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myList = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
            ListBox1.Text = string.Join(",", myList);
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, changed that in my code but still have an error on people.Add(TextBox1.Text);

Comment: @user2975108 - first time you're using Session, you have to put something there. Please, check my answer below, it checks, if any data in Session, and, if no, creates new list of strings. Direct copy paste must work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check, if there is anything in your session... On Button click:

```
people = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
//Create new, if null
if(people == null) 
    people = new List<string>();

people.Add(TextBox1.Text);

Session["mySession"] = people;
```

That is first. Second, on page #2 you have to do, on Page Load:

```
people = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
//Create new, if null
if(people == null) 
people = new List<string>();
ListBox1.DataSource = people;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Of course, it's better, if you move to some static method this part, to resolve code duplication:

```
public static List<string> GetPeopleFromSession(){
    var people = HttpContext.Current.Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
    //Create new, if null
    if(people == null) 
        people = new List<string>();
    return people;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
ListBox1.Text = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
```

You can't convert a list of strings to a string - you could on the other hand decide to display all of them e.g.

```
var myList = Session["mySession"] as List<string>;
ListBox1.Text = string.Join(",", myList);
```